# Voter not working in Symfony 3.3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have a Voter that is working perfectly in a controller but when i try to use it inside a service, it always return true although it has a "return false" statement.

The only difference i see is the way i call it.

In controller i use it this way:

```
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ver', $menu);
```

And in service i call it this way:

```
    $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ver', $menu);
```

In service i inject AuthorizationChecker and it works but it seems to run other Voters (i have only one).

In "security.yml" i have this:

```
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
```

Voter Code:

```
    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token){

    $usuario = $token->getUser();

    if (!$usuario instanceof Usuarios) {
        return false;
    }

    /** @var Menu $menu */
    $menu = $subject;


    switch ($attribute) {
        case self::VER:
            return false;
        case self::EDITAR:
            return false;
        case self::IMPRIMIR:
            return false;
    }

    throw new \LogicException('This code should not be reached!');
}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: There was problems with this release, did you tried to upgrade to 3.3.5?

Comment: I just upgrade (don't know there was a new version) but problem persist :(

Comment: I am guessing your voter is not actually getting called though I can't see why.  Maybe add a die statement just to verify.  I'm assuming your voter is properly tagged.

Comment: Yes, my Voter is called. I have tried putting the die statement. And it works when called from controller. I can't imagine what is happening.

Comment: When "called from a service" you are not using a console command?  And you are not calling it from the constructor of the service?  Maybe show the relevant bits of the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer.

The difference between this ...:

```
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ver', $menu);
```

... and this ...:

```
    $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ver', $menu);
```

... is the way they inform you about the result.

First statement throws a DenyAccessException but second statement returns a boolean (don't throw exception).

I didn't realise of that :)

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Voters are not supposed to return boolean values, but integers. You can see them in VoterInterface alongside with their constants: `ACCESS_GRANTED` (1), `ACCESS_ABSTAIN` (0) and `ACCESS_DENIED` (-1). Returning boolean will cause subsequent strategy to perform equality check **with** type jugling, which might cause hard to detect security issues, if you're not knowing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ver', $menu);
```

and

```
    $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ver', $menu);
```

will do the same job.

Please check the content of `$menu` in both service and controller.

`$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted($attributes, $object = null, $message = 'Access Denied.')` is a shortcut to `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted($attributes, $object)`

Your custom voter needs to implement VoterInterface or extend Voter, which makes creating a voter even easier. Did you ?

Check the official doc to check up the good implementation of your voter. https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: It should be the same but it doesn't return the same. My Voter extends Voter and it works perfecly in a Controller but it doesn't works well inside a service.